# bootstrap alert-dismissible on button click shows but don't stay

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, alert

I Want to show an alert when we click on save button. Then the  alert will stay until I click close (x) on the top right corner.

Now the Alert shows but just only for 1 second. I want the alert to stay.

In the following button click It will show up a alert

```
<button  type='submit' id="submit"  name='submit'>Save Document</button>
```

My alert code

```
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
  </div>
```

This is my Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button#submit").click(function() {
    $(".alert").show();
  });
});
```

and this Is my Css

```
.alert{ display: none; }
```

Comment: Did you try to call `event.prevetDefault()` since your button has type=submit which triggers a form submission / page refresh

You would have to change lines accordingly:
`$(&quot;button#submit&quot;).click(function(event){event.preventDefault()  […]`

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("button#submit").click(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
    $(".alert").show();
  });
});  But its stops my from submission and insert into db

Comment: thats why you need to handle that action or let it bubble up if everything has passed checks.
or you could manually fire a `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`
- OR - jquery `$( "#myForm" ).submit();`

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
  $("button#submit").click(function( event ) { 
   event.preventDefault();
    $(".alert").show(); 
        $( "#form" ).submit();
   }); 
 }); This is not working. Sorry  I am not an expert.. but trying to learn

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is native behavior for the alert to disappear. See if you have JavaScript on the page that is targeting the class '.alert'.

Comment: no script on the page. May be because its a submit button. For only <a> tag its working.